# JPA: foreign Id is not automatically set when user is added in database

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have 2 classes user and authorities
I want that when a user is registered the fk in the authorities table is automatically setted with the user id created

[authorities table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8wfQ.png)

[user table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9iWd.png)

user class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "username")
private String username;

@Column(name = "password")
private String password;

@Column(name = "enabled")
private Byte enabled = 1;

@JsonManagedReference
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Authorities> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
```

Authorities class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "authorities")
public class Authorities {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "authority")
    private String authority;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_user")
    private User user;
```

this is the controller of the registration:

```
@PostMapping("registration" )
public String addUser(@ModelAttribute ("addUser") User user){
    String username = user.getUsername();
    String password = user.getPassword();
    userService.save(user);
    Authorities authorities = new Authorities(username,"ROLE_USER");
    authoritiesService.save(authorities);

    return "redirect:registration";
}
```

the dialect:

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

Edit:

I tried with this solution:

```
Authorities authorities = new Authorities(username,"ROLE_USER",user);
```

But i dont know if is correct or the fk should be assigned automatically

Comment: Take a look at this article, especially the section on bidirectional association https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: @CaptainAye thank you it helped so much, but i dont understand a thing, we have unidirectional and bidirectional association, but what is better? from the article I understood that bidirectional is always better since it performs less SQL statement.
so is it preferable to use this one or does it depend on the case?

Comment: It very much depends on the use case. Generally, unidirectional associations are much easier to manage, as you have only one end to perform all operations. If you're use case can be implemented with unidirectional association, go for it. In your example, if you only need to know authorities for each user, stay with @oneToMany relation first. You can always extend to bidirectional association if required later.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to call authoritiesService.save(authorities) to save your authorities, you need to do the opposite to what you did in the edit section:
add the authorities to the user object, save the user, the authorities will be saved automatically (Provided that you mapped them correctly).

```
@PostMapping("registration" )
public String addUser(@ModelAttribute ("addUser") User user){
    String username = user.getUsername();
    String password = user.getPassword();
    Authorities authorities = new Authorities(username,"ROLE_USER");
    user.getAuthorities().add(authorities);
    userService.save(user);
    return "redirect:registration";
}
```

Edit:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable( 
        name = "user_roles", 
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")}, 
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id")}
        ) 
    private Collection<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
```

Although your relation is not ManyToMany, but you can get something from this, try to play around the join columns.

Comment: I tried with this solutions but the result is the same, the fk is null and is not set automatically, i post the 2 entities im missing something?

Comment: Yes it work but when i cant do this: user.getSomething().add(something);
for example now im trying to implement the rememberMe i have a table auto populated with the token the date ecc when the user logIn with rememberMe option but the user fk in this table is null because i cant set it manually and i cant populate the table because is populated automatically